# how to set 'event_scheduler' in MS azure mysql

Tags: mysql, azure

I'm having problem trying to set 'event_scheduler = on' the MySQL server provided as part of the MS Azure service(i'm using 3 month trial version)

the error message is "ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation"

anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question is antique, but it's the only question on here regarding MS Azure and this error. I've figured it out. It's a permissions problem (obviously) and in order to get it resolved, you'll have to contact MS Azure and purchase their support plan, and you *might* get an engineer to work with you.

However, if you don't have a support plan, the only thing I've been able to come up with is to use WebJobs which seems to do the trick.

I ultimately wanted MySQL to purge all entries with a 'date' field that is older than the current day. So I created a PHP script with that SQL query, and used WebJobs to set up a cronjob to execute that script once a day. It did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late but this can help others who are looking for this.

Login to your Azure portal > ${your_sql_server} > click on "Server Parameters" tab and you should be able to set all your global parameters like "event_scheduler"